# jQuery easyUI conflict with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I am using easyUI datagrid component and I'm trying to add bootstrap dropdown  menu in a datagrid cell. The problem is when I click the dropdown button, the menu doesn't show.

When moving the menu outside the cell, or remove the cell 'datagrid-cell' class, it works fine.

No console errors shown. Here is the current HTML:

```
<div style="height:auto;" class="datagrid-cell undefined">
   <div class="select-grid-item-container">
      <div class="select-grid-row select-grid-row-item options-active">
         <div class="select-grid-options-dropdown">
            <span class="select-grid-options" data-toggle="dropdown">Options</span> 
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
               <li role="presentation"> <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" class="send-email">Send Email</a> </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if you any other details/code. Please do let me know if so.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the code at jsfiddle  , i just tried and clicking on options is showing the dropdown.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/d8mkjcm5/ (i have included bootstrap and jQuery ui js)

Comment: Not sure if that makes a difference, but I am actually using this library: http://www.jeasyui.com

Probably the class 'datagrid-cell' is non-existent in jQuery.